# LabVIEW (Connected to instruments via PCI-GPIB ) to Study Diode Characteristics

Tags: labview, gpib

I am new to LabVIEW. I wish to plot IV, CV curve (characteristics) of a diode. Can somebody help me with the code. I have instruments such as HP 6611c (DC power supply) and HP 34401A (Multimeter) and LabVIEW 8.5. I want to use this instruments to study characteristics of a diode. I don't know how to use instruments drivers. Is there any way to do this without using instruments drivers, by just coding a program and using the GPIB Read GPIB write etc , i.e using SCPI commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Questions in the range of please help me or how do I do this are usually not really appreciated here. You are better of asking a specific question about a specific problem.

Regarding your question just coding your own program using GPIB. Yes you can do this, but in principle you are writing your own driver. Usually this is unnecessary and time consuming and you are better of using the supplied LabVIEW drivers. NI supplies the drivers here: [HP 34401A Driver](http://sine.ni.com/apps/utf8/niid_web_display.download_page?p_id_guid=014E7F05D12C6F8BE0440003BA7CCD71) and here [HP 6611c](http://sine.ni.com/apps/utf8/niid_web_display.model_page?p_model_id=1743). Usually the drivers are accessible and you will see all the GPIB calls that are made by the driver. If you want something really want to write your own driver for something special (for speed or something else) it is easiest and fastest to just copy paste the parts you need from the actual driver.

As a tip I think there are some LabVIEW examples for acquiring and plotting IV curves. Also think what your main goals is for your programming, presumably making IV measurements and not writing drivers. Supported programs and solutions you can get from the internet are quite often better than if you try to write it your self.

Comment: The drivers will often have examples included as well.